# Regex is finding match but not counting if only matches once

Tags: regex, vb.net, match

I've written a little piece of code where the user will write a word or sentence in a textbox, click a button and the text in a rich text box is searched, deleting the searched for text if found. That works. 
What should also happen is that a message box will pop up saying "Phrase has been deleted X times." The issue I'm having is that this only works if it's found more than once. If it's found once, my programme seems to view it as being found 0 times. 
The code is below, any help would be much appreciated -

```
Try
    Dim Selection As New Regex(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim deletion As New Regex("\n" & Selection.ToString & "\n")

    Dim Stripped As String = Regex.Replace(RichTextBox1.Text, deletion.ToString, vbCr, RegexOptions.Multiline)
    RichTextBox1.Clear()
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(Stripped)

    Dim matchcount = deletion.Matches(RichTextBox1.Text).Count
    If matchcount > 0 Then
        MsgBox("'" & Selection.ToString & "'" & " has been deleted " & matchcount.ToString & " times.")
    Else
        MsgBox("'" & Selection.ToString & "'" & " has not been found on a line on its own.")
    End If
```

Comment: You count the matches in `Stripped` after a regex replace operation. Also, you seem to want `Dim deletion As New Regex("[\r\n]*^" & Selection.ToString & "\r?$[\r\n]*")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are searching `\n something \n`. I.e., you are looking for two `vbLf`, but the fist line will not be preceded by a linefeed and the lines might be separated by `vbCrLf`. You can match the beginning of line with `^` and the end of line with `$`.

Also, I'm not sure what your intention is. Since `RichTextBox1` contains the stripped text, i.e., the text not containing the search pattern anymore, how can you find this text in it with `deletion.Matches(RichTextBox1.Text)`?

You are declaring a `Regex` named `Selection` but you are never using it as such. Instead you are extracting the pattern with `Selection.ToString`, which is of course exactly the same as the one you entered as `TextBox1.Text`.

You should count the matches **before** doing the replace. Also, you must use the same options for counting and replacing

```
Dim deletion As New Regex("^" & TextBox1.Text & "$", RegexOptions.Multiline)

Dim matchcount = deletion.Matches(RichTextBox1.Text).Count
RichTextBox1.Text = deletion.Replace(RichTextBox1.Text, vbCrLf)
```

If `TextBox1.Text` is supposed to contain a regex pattern, then creating the Regex object like this is okay; however, if it is supposed to contain plain text, then you must escape it.

```
Dim deletion As New Regex("^" & Regex.Escape(TextBox1.Text) & "$", 
    RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

Otherwise special regex characters will do their magic instead of being treated as plain text. Example

```
Regex.Escape("This is a sentence.")   --->   "This is a sentence\."
```

Comment: This is a very small part of a much bigger project, involving a lot of moving things around, so I hadn't noticed, and you're completely right, that I was searching after the replacement was made. The "selection to string" came because there's two options (highlighting text being the other) but you're also quite right that I don't actually need to specify that since tweaking the code to separate them. This is all very helpful, thanks so much for taking the time to provide such a detailed response. So helpful, and informative